# Why is firefox coloring certain characters, and is there a workaround?

Tags: css, character-encoding, char, character

I was just writing some css when I stumbled across this weird 'thingy'. I had the following css:

```
div:after {
    content: '✔';
    color: red;
}
```

And instead of showing a red check mark it showed a green one. This only happens in Firefox. Is this some kind of bug or is this supposed to be the 'expected' result. I found a list with multiple characters which firefox converts to custom 'icons'. You can find the list here: http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb

I also came up with an image showing the differences in Firefox and Chrome. 
[image]

Update:

A screenshot based on the jsFiddle provided by @LinkinTED

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working good here http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/tz84qqje/, FF24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above behaviour occurs because the fallback fonts for these specific characters are loaded incorrectly.
First it loads `Segoe UI Emoji`, if that doesn't exist it will load `Segoe UI Symbol`. The Segoe UI Emoji font (in windows 8) are pre-styled, which makes it impossible to style them with CSS. With that in mind, the solution is easy, just use the right font (`Segoe UI Symbol`).

Check this new Fiddle to see this solution in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/tz84qqje/2/

Source:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1054780

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me when I use direct hex codes ...

```
div:after {
content: '✔';
color: #ff0000;
}
```